# Right way to add a per-request response delay to a custom HttpService

Tags: armeria

Here's my current implementation of `HttpService.serve()`

```
@Override
public HttpResponse serve(ServiceRequestContext ctx, HttpRequest req) throws Exception {
    return HttpResponse.from(req.aggregate().thenApply(ahr -> {
        MyResponse myResponse = Utils.handle(ahr);
        HttpResponse httpResponse Utils.toResponse(myResponse);
        return httpResponse; 
    }));
}
```

I have a user-defined response delay which can vary per each individual request-response, and this is available in the `myResponse` object.

What is the best way to apply this delay in a non-blocking way, I can see some `delay` API-s but they are protected within `HttpResponse` . Any extra tips or pointers to the streaming API design or decorators would be helpful. I'm really learning a lot from the Armeria code base :)

Comment: Great to know that you enjoyed playing with Armeria. Please feel free to let us know if you have anything that gave you difficulties while working with it. Even a tiniest thing may help us improve Armeria. 

Comment: @trustin - thank you as always for your detailed and humble responses. I indeed need to get more experience with reactive / subscribers etc - and hope to provide some feedback on the Armeria WebClient at the very least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the desired delay even before consuming the request body, you can simply use `HttpResponse.delayed()`:

```java
@Override
public HttpResponse serve(ServiceRequestContext ctx, HttpRequest req) throws Exception {
    return HttpResponse.delayed(
        HttpResponse.of(200),
        Duration.ofSeconds(3),
        ctx.eventLoop());
}
```

If you need to consume the content or perform some operation to calculate the desired delay, you can combine `HttpResponse.delayed()` with `HttpResponse.from()`:

```java
@Override
public HttpResponse serve(ServiceRequestContext ctx, HttpRequest req) throws Exception {
    return HttpResponse.from(req.aggregate().thenApply(ahr -> {
    //                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        MyResponse myResponse = Utils.handle(ahr);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = Utils.toResponse(myResponse);
        Duration myDelay = Utils.delayMillis(...);
        return HttpResponse.delayed(httpResponse, myDelay, ctx.eventLoop());
        //                  ^^^^^^^
    });
}
```

If the delay is not actually delay but waiting for something to happen, you can use `CompletableFuture.thenCompose()` which is more powerful:

```java
@Override
public HttpResponse serve(ServiceRequestContext ctx, HttpRequest req) throws Exception {
    return HttpResponse.from(req.aggregate().thenCompose(ahr -> {
    //                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^
        My1stResponse my1stRes = Utils.handle(ahr);

        // Schedule some asynchronous task that returns another future.
        CompletableFuture<My2ndResponse> myFuture = doSomething(my1stRes);

        // Map the future into an HttpResponse.
        return myFuture.thenApply(my2ndRes -> {
            HttpResponse httpRes = Utils.toResponse(my1stRes, my2ndRes);
            return httpRes;
        });
    });
}
```

For even more complicated workflow, I'd recommend you to look into Reactive Streams implementations such as Project Reactor and RxJava, which provides the tools for avoiding the callback hell.